# SQL query for forecasting

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, reporting, forecasting

We are trying to generate forecast report for data warehouse related to revenue data using SQL Server 2012.

We are trying to write SQL for the following scenario:

For forecasts and shipped numbers, we need quantities by Corp Acct Code by year by month by SKU for 2016. The catch here is we can only have UNIT SKUs. So any case sku will have to have its number multiplied with the resp conversion factor and then entered against the Unit SKU ID

This is output :

```
CorpAcctCode  Year  Month  StockCode         TotalShippedQty  TotalForecastedQty
NY            2016  April  abcd-gef-12hi-01  2000             5000
NY            2016  May    abcd-gef-12hi-01  0                5000
```

We tried the following query

```
select distinct 
    rtrim(CONVERT(nvarchar, CONVERT(varchar, CorpAcctCode))) As CorpAcctCode,
    year(getdate()) as Year,
    CASE n
       WHEN 1 THEN 'Jan'
       WHEN 2 THEN 'Feb'
       WHEN 3 THEN 'Mar'
       when 4 then 'Apr'
       when 5 then 'May'
       when 6 then 'Jun'
       when 7 then 'Jul'
       when 8 then 'Aug'
       when 9 then 'sep'
       when 10 then 'Oct'
       when 11 then 'Nov'
       when 12 then 'Dec' 
    END AS Month,
    ForecastQty,
    StockCode
from 
    TABLE1 arc1
inner join 
    (select distinct 
         CorpAcctCode, b.Customer, fc.ForecastQty, fc.StockCode 
     from 
         View_Forecast fc 
     left join 
         table2 b on b.Customer = fc.Customer) b on arc1.Customer = b.Customer
cross join
    (select 1 union 
     select 2 union
     select 3 union
     select 4 union
     select 5 union
     select 6 union
     select 7 union
     select 8 union
     select 9 union
     select 10 union
     select 11 union
     select 12) AS Nums(n)
order by 
    CorpAcctCode
```

How do I achieve total forecast column or is that other way to write above scenario?

Comment: please post some sample data from the `View_Forecast` table

Comment: here is sample data extracted from the View_Forecast.: sample data link is View_Forecast :http://paste.ofcode.org/EnW2A8b8qn7MTvUTZJUyTT

Comment: That is too many for me to process. Can you update the question with the sample data in consumable `INSERT INTO` ... format ? And also please post the corresponding expected result

Comment: This is read only database. We do not have permission  to access or apply into  insert statement.  i can post few rows of data for ex top 2 rows of _Forecast table . is that ok.

Comment: i mean post the sample data like `insert into #arc1 (col1, col2 ...) values ( .. )`

Comment: Please find Insert statement for each table invovled in it . here is link http://paste.ofcode.org/FzNRfef3UK2m3VSZS8Pjkv

Comment: Here is small amount  of data it may help you to load : http://paste.ofcode.org/NcxceZREY7WWgFJ9n2yVLU Please let me know if  this links works for you. thanks